# System values from Product attributes are not recovered by filter

Tags: magento2

I have a custom product attributes. In backoffice, the values are well recovered, but in layer navigation, the filter can't find the values

Any ideas ?

This is the attribute creation :

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);  

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'longueur_tasse_vertuo', [
        'type'  => 'text',
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Longueur de tasse Vertuo',
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => 'Cpy\Catalog\Model\Config\Product\CupSizeVertuooption',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'group' => '',
        'sort_order' => 203,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => true,
        'comparable' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true
    ]
);
```

This is the source model

```
class CupSizeVertuooption extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\AttributeFactory
     */
    protected $_eavAttrEntity;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttrEntity
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttrEntity
    ) {
        $this->_eavAttrEntity = $eavAttrEntity;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Espresso', 'value' => '1'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Double Espresso', 'value' => '2'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Gran Lungo', 'value' => '3'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Mug', 'value' => '4'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Alto', 'value' => '5'];

        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve flat column definition
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColumns()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

        return [
            $attributeCode => [
                'unsigned' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'extra' => null,
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => $attributeCode . ' column',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Indexes(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatIndexes()
    {
        $indexes = [];

        $index = 'IDX_' . strtoupper($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        $indexes[$index] = ['type' => 'index', 'fields' => [$this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode()]];

        return $indexes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Select For Flat Attribute update
     *
     * @param int $store
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return $this->_eavAttrEntity->create()->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

As you can see, he is able to recover the attributes...but not his content.

[image: front filter]

Nevertheless, if I go to check in my backend properties the values are well there;

[image: backend attribute properties]

Also, this is the block definition :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.cafe.cupsize" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cafe/cup-size.phtml" before="product.info.price" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getLongueurTasse</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">longueur_tasse</argument>
        <argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-nespresso-cupsize</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Taille des tasses :</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="nespresso-cupsize"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.cafe.cupsize.vertuo" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cafe/vertuo/cup-size.phtml" before="product.info.price" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getLongueurTasseVertuo</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">longueur_tasse_vertuo</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-nespresso-cupsize-vertuo</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Taille des tasses :</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="nespresso-cupsize"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Issue still not fixed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue belongsz to the class `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php`

The method

```
protected function _getIndexableAttributes($multiSelect)
{
    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
        ['ca' => $this->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute')],
        'attribute_id'
    )->join(
        ['ea' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
        'ca.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id',
        []
    )->where(
        $this->_getIndexableAttributesCondition()
    );

    if ($multiSelect == true) {
        $select->where('ea.backend_type = ?', 'varchar')->where('ea.frontend_input = ?', 'multiselect');
    } else {
        $select->where('ea.backend_type = ?', 'int')->where('ea.frontend_input IN( ? )', ['select', 'boolean']);
    }
    return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($select);
}
```

For multiselect, the required type was varchar while my attribute had a type text.

So all we have to do is to change the attribute type to varchar and then play the indexer once again to get the association geing written in the table `catalog_product_index_eav` making it possible to be appearing in the filter.

This is for the quick and immediate fix. In the same time, I send the issue to magento to make this multiselect where condition be able to read both text and varchar type, feel free to check it : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29676